# External HDD will not spin down

Tags: usb, power-management, hard-drive

I am having an issue with my external hard drive and it is quite annoying.

So, I [purchased the Samsung M3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-Slimline-Portable-Hard-Drive/dp/B008PABFX8), for the sole purpose of acting as a mass storage device for my Raspberry Pi. Lovely.

I originally had it mounted with `ntfs-3g`, that was REALLY slow and performance was awful. I reformatted the drive with an ext4 filesystem, mounted it with noatime. Cool, everything is working.

Except, the drive **does not spin down**. It is constantly spinning, 24/7. This did not happen when it was mounted with ntfs-3g, but ever since switching to `ext4` it has just not stopped spinning.

I have attempted the following to fix it:

`sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda` - any hdparm command returns

`/dev/sda:
 issuing standby command
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 01 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

I then decided to try `sudo udisks --set-spindown /dev/sda --spindown-timeout 20`, which returned `Setting spindown failed: Cannot spindown device`.

I just can't seem to get it working, even though it was perfectly fine with ntfs-3g.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try http://superuser.com/questions/651880/force-spin-down-of-external-hard-drive-on-linux-raspberry-pi ?

Comment: It may be because the OS keeps writing or reading from the drive. I suspect ext4 uses a journal? That may be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have posted this months ago, this is how I resolved it.

- Created a folder, applied the appropriate permissions
- Edited /etc/fstab
- Added the following:

  ```
  /dev/sda1   /media/usbhdd   ext4   defaults,noatime   0 0
  ```
- Save, reboot

And everything was working perfectly. Hope it helps people

*Where /media/usbhdd is the folder you added